# Export Recipes from Recipe module

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I'm working on a site with the [Recipe module](https://drupal.org/project/recipe) for cooking recipes installed on it. According to the linked page, it's possible to import and export recipes to and from that module. Unfortunately, I can't find where that can be done. Does anybody know how to do it?

I'm fairly new to Drupal, so I'm sure I'm just overlooking something obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you enabled one of the additional modules that allow you to export the content, e.g. "Recipe recipeML" or "Recipe MasterCook4". They will provide you with extra pages where you can import/export the content.

For example, "recipeML" will add new pages for importing/exporting the recipes on the following paths: `admin/content/recipe/export_multi` and `admin/content/recipe/import_multi`.
Visit `admin/content`, then click on "Recipes" from the list of local tasks and from there you can go to the import/export page.

Hope this makes sense.